# Bind to a property and Element value - WPF binding

Tags: wpf, checkbox, listbox

I have a `checkbox` which is binded to a object's property "`IsValidCustomer`" and I have a `listview` that holds some customers.
Whenever My user selects any `Customer` in the list, I want the `Checkbox` `Checked` property to set to `False` that means my "`IsValidCustomer`" property also will set to `False` automatically. Is there any way of achieving this using WPF bindings?

Any help in this regard would be highly appriciated.

Regards

-Srikanth

Answer (score 0):

- First make sure that your view's `Datacontext` is set to a `viewmodel` that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` `interface` then add a `SelectedCustomer` property that will hold the selected `Customer` from the `ListView`,
- Each time the `SelectedCustomer` is set, check its value and set the `IsValidCustomer` property 
  here the full code :

the View model

```
 public class Customer
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Id { get; set; }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Customer _selectedCustomer;
    public Customer SelectedCustomer
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedCustomer;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedCustomer == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _selectedCustomer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            IsValidCustomer = (_selectedCustomer == null);

        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _listCustomers;
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> ListCustomers
    {
        get
        {
            return _listCustomers;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_listCustomers == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _listCustomers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private bool _isValidCustomer = false;
    public bool IsValidCustomer
    {
        get
        {
            return _isValidCustomer;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_isValidCustomer == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _isValidCustomer = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and the view

```
  <StackPanel>
    <CheckBox Content="IsValidCustomer" IsChecked="{Binding IsValidCustomer,Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListCustomers}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomer,Mode=TwoWay}"></ListView>        
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have something like this in your model :

```
     private bool _IsValidCustomer;

    public bool IsValidCustomer
    {
        get { return _IsValidCustomer; }
        set
        {
            _IsValidCustomer= value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsValidCustomer"));
        }
    }
```

Set the Binding for that bool property.

```
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsValidCustomer, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"/>
            </Style>
```

Your CheckBox will be bound to this also :

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsValidCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

So, i assume you start with that IsValidCustomer set to true. And on selecting each row, you want to set it to false.

You will need an inverse boolean converter for this:

```
public class InverseBooleanConverter: IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(bool))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a boolean");

        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Hi Olaru.. Seems this is working for me .. excpt, when I select Checkbox or any one listitem it is selecting all list items..  Not sure why it was.. Only change i have done is IsValidCustomer property is at Window level datacontext and list datasource is list of customers and so, I have used FindAncetor to get the IsValidCustomer.. Any Idea why all of my listview items are selecting.. also, my listview's view is not really listviewitems, rather it is a Grid binded inside a listview.view.. Thanks for the help so far..

Comment: @SrikanthAlluri IsValidCustomer should reside in the Model. This way, each Row will have its own state. I think you have to differentiate each of the customers. While one is not valid, other may be and so on. Setting that in the context of the Window, all of the bindings will refer to the same property and i am sure that's not the behaviour you want.

Comment: @SrikanthAlluri One more thing, implement INotifyPropertyChanged for the Customer class too and add the PropertyChanged event on your set branch in each property.